# Taking screenshot crashes app

Tags: android, crash, screenshot

I tried creating a screenshot app, but somehow I can not get the root content.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.MeasureSpec;

public class Screenshot extends Activity {

    public final String TAG = "Screen";


    String output; 
    public String takeScreen(String savepathname) {

        Log.e(TAG, "TAKESCREEN 01");

        //View content = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //View content = findViewById(R.id.layoutroot);

        //View content = getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        Log.e(TAG, "TAKESCREEN 01.5");
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);

        Log.e(TAG, "TAKESCREEN 02");

        //View content = findViewById(R.id.layoutroot);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        File file = new File( Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + savepathname);

        Log.e(TAG, "TAKESCREEN 03");

        try{
            Log.e(TAG, "TAKESCREEN 04");

            file.createNewFile();
            Log.e(TAG, "TAKESCREEN 05");
            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            Log.e(TAG, "TAKESCREEN 06");
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, ostream);
            Log.e(TAG, "TAKESCREEN 07");
            ostream.close();
            output = "Successfully saved -> "+savepathname;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            output = "Screenshot.java -> "+e;
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

If I use findViewbyId, I only get this error: "layoutroot cannot be resolved or is not a field".

While using "getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content);" works, but then the app crashes in that part.

Could someone help me with that, please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Where is the `onCreate()` method? You need to call setContentView() inside that method.

Comment: setContentView(R.layout.main); is in another class. That class I posted should just be used for taking the screenshots. I also already tried defining the View content as a function in the main class in which onCreate() is used, but if I use this function in the other class, there is exactly the same result.

Comment: Screen class extends `Activity`. Maybe what you are trying is doable, IDK, but I believe it is bad practice. If you want to use a view, than you need to show the activity where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement this part too? If you didn't, place it inside your *Screen* class. By the way, I strongly believe that going over [this activity lifecycle tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html) will help you.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Assuming that *button1* and *layoutroot* are properly described within *activity_main.xml*